# why does slicing an ndarray reshape it?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a nx1 array, a:

```
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

when I slice it with

```
a[:-1,0]
```

it becomes:

```
a([0,0])
```

and I'm not able to use it in plot (now the dimensions are wrong, even though the length is correct). I've tried

```
a[:-1,0].T
```

and

```
transpose(a[:-1,0])
```

to no avail.

How do I slice without changing the shape? (I want to keep it in column form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say `a = numpy.zeros((3,1))` , then

```
    b = a[:-1,:]
```

will give you a column vector.

```
    array([[ 0.],
           [ 0.]])
```

When slicing a numpy array, you have to distinguish between adressing the content of a column, e.g. `a[:,0]`, and adressing the column itself, e.g. `a[:,0:1]` or - in this case - `a[:,:]`.

Comment: `a[:-1,:1] == a[:-1,0:1]` would work to pull out the 0th column in an array with more than one, as well.  [Here, I think even `a[:-1]` would suffice.]

Comment: For 2D arrays there is also the option of using `matrix`, which retains its 2D shape even when accessing a single column or row. It does return a single scalar, not an array of shape `(1, 1)`, if you access a single element.